# flow fails on union type even with if/else

Tags: flowtype

In the flow [documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html), it states about typeof "This type test is particularly useful in conjunction with union types."  The following, however does not pass flow's scythe:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var fnify = function(key: string | (x: number, y: any) => string) {
    var fnkey = typeof(key) === 'function' ? key : (t) => key;
    new EventEmitter().emit(fnkey(0), 0);
}
```

Flow complains that it does not know the return value of fnkey, which is odd, as it is guaranteed to be a string from the signature of the function. What does go through is:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var fnify = function(key: string | (x: number, y: any) => string) {
    var fnkey = typeof(key) === 'function'
        ? key
        : (t) => typeof(key) === 'string' ? key : null;
    var kludge = fnkey(0);
    if (kludge) {
      new EventEmitter().emit(kludge, 0);
    }
}
```

But the latter seems unnecessarily verbose.  Is this a feature? Bug? Is there something wrong in the first snippet that makes flow irate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `key` can change in the function body, either use a [`const` binding](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats)

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var fnify = function(key: string | (x: number, y: any) => string) {
  const k = key;
  var fnkey = typeof(k) === 'function' ? k : (t) => k;
  new EventEmitter().emit(fnkey(0), 0);
}
```

or set `experimental.const_params=true` in the `[option]` section of your `.flowconfig`

Comment: Works great w/ `experimental.const_params`!